# dupliacte records based on gaps bettwen two columns

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have this data:

```
   rn   sex value   from    to
    1   w   0.019500000000000000    1   25
    2   w   0.018000000000000002    26  26
    3   w   0.019500000000000000    27  28
    4   w   0.021000000000000001    29  29
    5   w   0.022500000000000002    30  30
    6   w   0.024000000000000000    31  31
    7   w   0.025500000000000001    32  32
    8   w   0.026999999999999999    33  33
    9   w   0.028500000000000001    34  34
    10  w   0.029999999999999998    35  35
    11  w   0.031500000000000000    36  36
    12  w   0.034500000000000002    37  37
    13  w   0.036000000000000004    38  38
```

and i would like to duplicate records based on gaps between from to
so above data shoud look like this:
25

```
1   w   0.019500000000000000    1
1   w   0.019500000000000000    2
1   w   0.019500000000000000    3
1   w   0.019500000000000000    4
1   w   0.019500000000000000    5
1   w   0.019500000000000000    6
1   w   0.019500000000000000    7
1   w   0.019500000000000000    8
1   w   0.019500000000000000    9
1   w   0.019500000000000000    10
1   w   0.019500000000000000    11
1   w   0.019500000000000000    12
1   w   0.019500000000000000    13
1   w   0.019500000000000000    14
1   w   0.019500000000000000    15
1   w   0.019500000000000000    16
1   w   0.019500000000000000    17
1   w   0.019500000000000000    18
1   w   0.019500000000000000    19
1   w   0.019500000000000000    20
1   w   0.019500000000000000    21
1   w   0.019500000000000000    22
1   w   0.019500000000000000    23
1   w   0.019500000000000000    24
1   w   0.019500000000000000    25
2   w   0.018000000000000002    26
3   w   0.019500000000000000    27
3   w   0.019500000000000000    28
```

Im trying do do this by connect by clause, but no luck for now.
Mayby someone has diffrent idea/approach?

Comment: Tag the DBMS that you are using.

Comment: tags edited - 12c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE in Oracle.  The syntax is:

```
with recursive r_cte(rn, sex, value, from, to) as (
      select rn, sex, value, from, to
      from t
      union all
      select rn, sex, value, from + 1, to
      from r_cte r
      where from < to
     )
select rn, sex, value, from
from r_cte
order by rn, from;
```

Of course, `from` and `to` are awful column names -- because those are SQL keywords.  If those are the real names, they should be escaped.

The more traditional method is to generate a list of numbers and then use these:

```
with n as (
      select level - 1 as n
      from (select max(t - f + 1) as range
            from t
           ) t
      connect by level <= range
     )
select rn, sex, value, f + n
from t join
     n
     on n <= (t - f)
order by rn, f + n;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4288f60b221a99f8cbe92ffa90365007) is a db<>fiddle for this method.

Comment: I renamed columns to questions to be more cleared. On DB they have diffrent names.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server you can use recursive *cte* :

```
with r_cte (rn, sex, value, from, to) as (
     select rn, sex, value, from, to
     from table t
     union all
     select rn, sex, value, from + 1, to
     from r_cte r
     where from < to
)
select rn, sex, value, from
from r_cte
order by rn, from
option (maxrecursion 0); -- remove this for oracle
```

Note : Different database will have different syntax.

Comment: :) Thanks, but i mean Oracle, visible in tags